# What language is used on production? iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I've developed an application on my mother tongue, which is spanish, and I'm now using localization to add other languages, mainly english. My doubt is:

---

#### If someone downloads my application in let's say Germany, will they get the application on english or on spanish?

---

Currently my development language inside Xcode is spanish (latin america), but on iTunes-Connect the main language is set to english. I'm not sure which language will be used in those cases, thank you for sharing with me.

Answer (score 0):

When the user installs the app if the device language isn't there between your localization the default 1 will be set

Comment: Can I set the default to english and still use spanish as the development language?